# css3 rotation 3d on chrome and firefox

Tags: css, rotation, css-transitions

(First of all I'm sorry for my english!)
I'm developing a site that uses 3D rotation ([link](http://www.lucagarbin.it/home.html)), there is no problems on Safari but on Chrome (19.0.1084.46) and Firefox (12.0) it doesn't work correctly.

On Firefox if you switch several times between "porftolio" and "profile", the face with profile disappears.

On chrome the face "profilo" appears when the rotation is already playing.

Can you help me?

Comment: Great concept and execution of the design on your site!! Love the way you are using these transition. I think you're making CSS3 proud.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change or delete :

```
#profilo .pad {
padding-left: 30px;}
```